# Is a Docker Container of CD microservices provided from anywhere?

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5

I saw a following movie, and it's mentioning about Docker Container.

[Introducing SDL Web 8.5 – A Technical Deep Dive](http://www.sdl.com/video/Introducing-SDL-Web-8.5-A-Technical-Deep-Dive/115479/?mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiWm1Nek9UWTVNRFUzWm1RNSIsInQiOiJvTlwvVGFIV29tOHpKTTB5MmQ5Mjc2cVRmd25tZFBnYklVOG5aYTZXd25JbDl6K0RFWFp2aGxERGVQRlhnNlA3YWU0ZVVmNzhwTzEwK0J0WDhScGszOEhOSDhiXC8xd3doYVdjM1gyaWlsSnc0TWFhTTVFZDdIdXBad1RNK3YzUFFXIn0%3D)

It seems very efficient to create a Docker Container that contains all microservices(Discovery Service, Content Depoyer etc.)

I'd like to ask following questions to know how I can get such a Docker Container.

1. Does SDL provide Docker Container?
2. Is it possible to get such Docker Container from Docker hub?
3. Is it required to create a Docker Container by myself?

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid at the moment it's not provided official SDL docker containers, but there are a lot of groups that are creating and registering their own containers.

And due to license issues it seems difficult to think in a global solution, although I know there are some works on it. (Also thinking in the official SDL support in a docker environment)

There are people using docker for containers of the microservices (deployer, discovery, etc.) but I think there are some limitations with the content manager itself, as Windows images doesn't seem to work as well as linux images.

Answer (score 4):

Q: Does SDL provide Docker Container?

A: No, AFAIK only docker file can get it from SDL

Q: Is it possible to get such Docker Container from Docker hub?

A: No

Q: Is it required to create a Docker Container by myself?

A: Yes

@Peter Kjaer Created docker files, If you want to run the UDP CD services in Docker containers, hopefully, this can serve as a starting point for you:

https://github.com/pkjaer/docker-cd-services

There are some manual steps involved since It does not include the actual Tridion files and such, but they are all pretty quick to do follow the steps in the repository.

I hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Any news on official Docker containers provided by SDL? Is it available with SDL Tridion Sites 9?
SDL Tridion Sites 9 date sheet mentions docker container support for flexible deployment, however no detailed documentation on it.

Comment: This is not an answer, please remove this answer and move to comment or questions

Comment: You are correct, this is not an answer! However this is very popular follow on question. I added it here, instead of asking new question.